# Magento2: Shipment issue in admin order

Tags: admin, magento2.2, php-7, shipment

I trying to create a shipment with track id for the order.

but it displays 404 error in chrome browser after enable bundling option in production mode.

[image]

How to solve the issue.

Thanks.

And the shipment submit call was canceled.

[image]

Comment: did you ever find a solution, same issue here

Comment: Its come from enabling js bundle option.